# A Hashing Problem

Tags: hash-function

**Hashing: You are to store objects identified by integers from [0..N − 1]. You expect never to have to store more than K objects. How would you design the hash function? Describe a general approach to design the hash function in terms of N and K. If N = 100000 and n = 50, give a concrete example of a hash function h. What is h(63455)?**

Here is my attempt:

*note: $n$ is the "space of IDs" I believe.

Also $k$ = "*k* objects to store at the most" I also *think*..

$N = 100,000$, $n = 50$

I picked a prime number $k$ such that $n \le k \le 2n$.

I let $k = 61 \implies 50 \le 61 \le 100$

Now I choose 3 numbers in the bounds of $0 \le (n-1) \implies$ some 3 numbers between 0 and 50

I picked $23,14,5$

So: $h_{23,14,5} (63,455)$

So: 63,455/61 = 1040 so $d_0 = 15$

1040/61 = 17 so $d_1 = 3 \implies d_2 = 3$

so:

$[(23*15) + (14*3) + (5*3) ] \mod 61  = 402$?

So the answer is $402$?

Comment: You didn't use $K$ at all and didn't define $n$.

Comment: Updated OP with what I think is correct. Again, unsure.

Comment: Well if the problem was original like that, then it must be a typographical error, probably they mean $K$ instead of $n$.

Comment: He did say there were some sort of typographical errors in the original type-up now that I do remember. I'm just trying to figure out if my solution is correct lol.

Answer (score 0):

Verified with my T.A. the correct solution. It seems I had some wrong values for some variables.

$63455/61 = 1040 \implies d_0 = 15$

$1040/61 = 17 \implies d_1 = 3$

$17$ is the last $q$ which $\implies d_2 = 17$

$\therefore h_{23,14,5} (63455) = (23*15) + (14*3) + [(5*17) \mod 61] = 411$

So the resulting hash is $411$